# JQuery: How do I select children of an sibling?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to know whether there is at least one item in the **dropdownlist**

This is my html

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="ddlHierarchyParentLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
   data-target="#" href="/page.html">
       No Parent (Top Hierarchy) 
       <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddlHierarchyParentLabel">
   @foreach (var item in Model.ParentHierarchyDic)
   {
     <li role="presentation">
       <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
         @item.Value
       </a>
     </li>
   }
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is me jquery

```
var $ul = $('#ddlHierarchyParentLabel').siblings('ul');
alert($ul.children('li').length);
```

I'm getting `0` when the alert pops up.

Thanks for helping

## UPDATE

```
//Process hierarchy
    $('.unprocHierarchy').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');            
        var url = '/Hierarchy/LoadEditTemplate/' + id;            
        $('#editHierarchy .modal-content').load(url);
        $('#editHierarchy').modal('show');

        var $ul = $('#ddlHierarchyParentLabel').siblings('ul');
        alert($ul.children('li').length);
    });
```

Comment: It works here - http://jsfiddle.net/jw82K/

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML...Perhaps you don't have any items in Model.ParentHierarchyDic

Comment: @LeeTaylor, Model.ParentHierarchyDic has value because when I display the page, I'm getting a dropdownList with items. But, I've noticed that the alert button appears before the modal. Is there any way to make those lines execute after the modal displays?

Comment: Presumably you are in control of calling the modal?

Comment: By the way, the dropdownList is inside the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the `shown.bs.modal` event, and it worked.

```
$editHierarchy.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var $ul = $('#ddlHierarchyParentLabel').siblings('ul');
        if($ul.children('li').length > 0)
        {
            $('#dispHierarchy').text('Select a Parent Hierarchy');
        }
    })
```